# Installing Android on iPhone 3G

Tags: ios, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Android on my non-Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6849/can-i-install-android-on-my-non-android-device)

I read somewhere that someone managed to get Android running on an iPhone 3G. Is there an easy  tutorial on how to do that?

It's just for testing purposes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

There are rater complete installation instructions on the wiki for the main project:

http://www.idroidproject.org/

Also, while you mentioned that it's just for testing, I can't stress enough how "beta" things are right now; this is not in a state suitable for end-users yet, and won't reasonably be until power management is complete. "Easy install tutorial" and "Android on iPhone" don't (at the time of this writing) go well together yet.

You'll have the most useful results with Android 1.6; while 2.2 (Froyo) builds are currently available (and I'm running it today), you'll find that it's a considerable amount of flux, with large pieces of basic functionality not there yet.

For additional questions or to search for common problems, the [iDroid forums](http://www.idroidproject.org/forum/) and IRC channel (#iphonelinux on irc.osx86.hu) are a good place to check.

Answer (score 4):

This PC world article walks you through it mostly

http://www.pcworld.com/article/196595/how_to_install_android_on_your_iphone.html

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like](http://www.redmondpie.com/install-android-2.2.1-froyo-on-iphone-3g-2g-using-bootlace-in-cydia-no-computer-required/) a new app called [Bootlace](http://www.idroidproject.org/wiki/Bootlace) has just been released for the iPhone 2G and 3G which makes it an incredibly easy set of clicks to get Android 2.2 running on a 3G. All you need is a jailbroken iPhone, and Bootlace does the rest for you.

See the [first link](http://www.redmondpie.com/install-android-2.2.1-froyo-on-iphone-3g-2g-using-bootlace-in-cydia-no-computer-required/) for a step by step tutorial.