# Can I install Google Play and run Android apps on my iPhone or iPad?

Tags: google-play-store, ios

I have an iPod Touch 4G (*this is where you all start screaming at me*). But I like the apps on Google Play. So if I downloaded a Google Play app on my computer and sent it to my iPod, would it work?

Comment: Nope. Sorry. The best bet for you is to find the app which you like contact the app developer/website to know whether a iDevice app is available and then use it.

Answer (score 2):

iOS and Android are two different systems. The only way to run Android Apps on iOS would be with an emulator.

There exists a project called iphodroid. It has a [Google Code project page](https://code.google.com/p/iphodroid/). The last update from the homepage is from May 2011 and given the rapid development regarding Android and iOS I doubt that this is still functional. You can try it, but at your own risk! I have never tested it.

Comment: See also: [Installing Android on iPhone 3G](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/664); [(how) can I install android on an iphone 4?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/847); [Can Android run on an iPad?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2297)