# How do I run an Android app on an iPhone?

Tags: android-emulator, ios, emulators

Based on my 30-60 minutes doing research on Google it seems there is no general solution for my question, but I wanted to double check on my favorite Q&A forum network, SE.

So, how can I run an Android app on an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you cannot run Android apps on an iPhone.

Based on my 30-60 minutes doing research on Google it seems there is no general solution.

- [This Android.SE post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/43874/can-i-install-google-play-and-run-android-apps-on-my-iphone-or-ipad)
- [This Quora question](https://qr.ae/pNr4V9)

However, *some* apps can be emulated on an iOS environment.

- Cydia is an emulator option for jailbroken iPhones, as mentioned in the Quora post cited above
- [iOSEmus](https://www.ikream.com/run-cydia-apps-iphone-without-jailbreak-25854) is an emulator option without the need of jailbreaking iPhones. By the way, I recommend [these installation instructions](https://troypoint.com/iosemus/).

I welcome anyone who has more general solutions.